# Converting my IP Bard to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, converters, invision-power-board

I have a Invision Power Board forum
and I am seriously thinking to change it and convert it to a Wordpress blog/news  site

since I have a lot of threads, and post replies my question is can I convert it too just Wordpress without adding bbpress plugin to Wordpress?
there I a paid service that could do teh conversion but into bbpress in Wordpress I just want the thread replies to appear in worpress as  comments on each post

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/